# How to setup UTC time from NTP server in C

Tags: c, utc

I want a time in this Format : **"t":"2020-03-06T12:09:38.000Z"**. How to do that in C ??

I tried below code to get time from NTP, but it not working for me.

Source Code :

```
// Get time From NTP and setup in SDK format
String GetTime(){                        // Setup UCT time from NTP server
    String Y,M,D1,D2,Ti;
    time_t now = time(nullptr);
    String T= (ctime(&now));
    //Serial.println(T);
    if (T.substring(20,22) == "20") {
        D1 = T.substring(8,9);          if (D1 == " ")D1 = "0";
        D2 = T.substring(9,10);
        M = Months(T.substring(4,7));   Y = T.substring(20,24);
        Ti = T.substring(11,19);
        return (Y+"-"+M+"-"+D1+D2+"T"+Ti+".000Z");
    }
      return (Y+"-"+M+"-"+D1+D2+"T"+Ti+".000Z");
}
```

it showing error for member substring and operand +.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about __C__ or __C#__? C is not C#.

Comment: This is not C code

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: how can i convert that C# code to C code ??

Comment: I want (t":"2020-03-06T12:09:38.000Z) this format of date and time. any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to setup UTC time from NTP server in C

> I tried below code to get time from NTP, but it not working for me.

OP's posted code is forming a string in local time, not UTC as `ctime()` is like `asctime(localtime(timer))`.

Code should use `gmtime(const time_t *timer);` for UTC.

There is the issue of string management.  In C, best to provide the buffer.

To form a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) like time stamp, use `strftime()`.

- `%F` is equivalent to “%Y-%m-%d” (the ISO 8601 date format). [tm_year, tm_mon, tm_mday]
- `%T` is equivalent to “%H:%M:%S” (the ISO 8601 time format). [tm_hour, tm_min, tm_sec]

To access sub-second units requires implementation specific code.  Sample code below uses `".000"`.

Some sample code to get OP started.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char* ISO8601(size_t sz, char dest[sz], time_t t) {
  struct tm *tm = gmtime(&t);
  if (tm == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  if (strftime(dest, sz, "%FT%T.000Z", tm) == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return dest;
}

int main(void) {
  char buf[100];
  char *s = ISO8601(sizeof buf, buf, time(NULL));
  if (s) {
    puts(s);
  }
}
```

Output

```
2020-08-25T08:19:42.000Z
```

Comment: Thank You ;) it working

Comment: how can i change .000Z (.mmmz) to display random value? (in your code 000Z constant right)

Comment: @vasim `sprintf(strchr(buf, '.'), "%.03uZ", rand()%1000u);` might work.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you could use ***strftime*** but your code is not C code.

```c
/* strftime example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime, strftime */

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

  strftime (buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z",timeinfo);
  puts (buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: Can u please give me one sample code to print (t":"2020-03-06T12:09:38.000Z) this format.

Comment: I edit my response

Comment: thanks you. I change my post

Comment: thanks, i tried both code. both are working